# activate python virtual environment with chef

Tags: python, ruby, chef-infra, virtualenv

I have a python virtual environment setup and I would like to activate the virtual environment using a chef recipe.

I'm trying to run a script resource

```
script "Start Virtual Enviroment" do
  interpreter "bash"
  code <<-EOH
  source /path/to/virtual_environment/bin/activate
  EOH
end
```

when I run the recipe chef does not throw any errors but the virtual environment does not start

I am expecting the command prompt to change..

```
 (virtual_environment)[root@po-12-3 to]#
```

When I run the command without a chef recipe it works

```
source /path/to/virtual_environment/bin/activate
```

I would like to avoid using a large third party cookbook like [python_pip](https://github.com/poise/python#python_pip)

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sourcing the activate script does activate the virtual environment, but only for the duration of that shell. That is to say, the virtual environment is activated on line 4 of your script and deactivated on line 5.

If you want to use the virtual environment, try something like:

```
script "Start Virtual Enviroment" do
  interpreter "bash"
  code <<-EOH
  source /path/to/virtual_environment/bin/activate
  python /path/to/my/python/program.py
  EOH
end
```